# Is a function like `purrr::map()` within `future.apply::future_apply()` also being ran in parallel?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, purrr, r-future

Sorry if these are a dumb questions, but I know next to nothing about how parallel processing works in practice.

My questions are:
- Q1. Is a function like `purrr::map()` within `future.apply::future_apply()` also being ran in parallel?
- Q2. What happens if I run `furrr::future_map()` inside of a `future.apply()` function?
- Q3. Assuming I did the above, would I include another `plan(multiprocess)` call before `furrr::future_map()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Author of the [future](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future) framework here.

> - Q1. Is a function like `purrr::map()` within `future.apply::future_apply()` also being ran in parallel?

No.  There is nothing in 'purrr' that runs in parallel.

> - Q2. What happens if I run `furrr::future_map()` inside of a `future.apply()` function?

It will fall back to run sequentially, which is `plan(sequential)`.  The reason for this is to protect against recursive, nested parallelism, which is rarely wanted.  This is explained in the future vignette ['A Future for R: Future Topologies'](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-3-topologies.html).  In some cases it is reasonable to nested parallelism, e.g. distributed processing on multiple machines where you in turn parallel across multiple cores on each machine.  This can be done by using

```r
plan(list(tweak(cluster, workers = c("n1", "n2", "n3")), multisession))
```

> - Q3. Assuming I did the above, would I include another `plan(multiprocess)` call before `furrr::future_map()`?

You don't want to set `plan()` "inside" you code / functions.  Leave the control of `plan()` to whoever will use your code/call your functions.  Also, one doesn't want to for a nested number of cores such as in `plan(list(tweak(multisession, workers = ncores), tweak(multisession, workers = ncores)))` because that will use `ncores^2` cores which will overload you computer.  Using the default number of cores as `plan(list(multisession, multisession))` will not have this problem, because in the second layer there will be only one core available anyway.